# JavaFX deselect text upon opening new TextInputDialog

Tags: java, javafx

I thought I found the answer with `deselect()` but strangely it doesn't do anything, the text is still all selected on opening.

```
TextInputDialog textInput = new TextInputDialog("whatever text");
textInput.initOwner(sentence.stage);
Optional<String> result = textInput.showAndWait();
if (result.isPresent()) {
   // process
}
textInput.getEditor().deselect();
```

Comment: `showAndWait()` doesn't return until the window is closed. So your `deselect()` call is too late. Does reordering your code help?

Comment: @Slaw Hmm no I tried that and it didn't help. I updated the code to include the result. I can paste the `deselect` line multiple times at different locations and it never has any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Dialog#showAndWait()` method does not return until the dialog is closed. That means your call to `deselect()` is too late. However, simply reordering your code does not appear to solve your problem. This looks like a timing issue; the text is probably selected when the field gains focus so you need to deselect the text *after* that happens. For example:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextInputDialog;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    var button = new Button("Show dialog...");
    button.setOnAction(
        ae -> {
          var textInput = new TextInputDialog("Some text");
          textInput.initOwner(primaryStage);
          Platform.runLater(textInput.getEditor()::deselect);
          textInput.showAndWait();
        });

    var root = new StackPane(button);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 300));
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

The `Runnable` passed to `runLater` is executed after the dialog is shown *and* after the text has been selected.