# JavaFx when I open dialog.showAndWait() how to focus TextArea

Tags: javafx

```
public Node dialog(){
        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.setPrefWidth(200);
        root.setPrefHeight(200);
        Button button = new Button("Dialog");
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
            TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
            dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(textArea);
            ButtonType ok = new ButtonType("OK", ButtonBar.ButtonData.OK_DONE);
            ButtonType cancel = new ButtonType("Cancel", ButtonBar.ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
            DialogPane dialogPane = dialog.getDialogPane();
            dialogPane.getButtonTypes().addAll(ok, cancel);
            textArea.requestFocus();
            dialog.showAndWait();
        });
        root.getChildren().add(button);
        return root;
    }
```

[image]

I try use `textArea.requestFocus();` before `dialog.showAndWait();` but when dialog open it always
focus OK Button. How to foucs textArea when dialog first open?

Comment: I try `dialog.setOnShown(e -> textArea.requestFocus())` but still foucs ok button

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaFX deselect text upon opening new TextInputDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69984866/javafx-deselect-text-upon-opening-new-textinputdialog)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```java
dialog.setOnShown(event -> {
    Platform.runLater(textArea::requestFocus);
    event.consume();
});
dialog.showAndWait();
```